# The equation $y'=1+y^4$ blows up in finite time

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that the equation $$y'=1+y^4 \:, y(0)=0$$ has a maximal solution with a bounded domain.

The existence and unicity of such a maximal solution is granted by Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem.

I tried a proof by contradiction for the boundedness. One promising way would be to use the fundamental theorem of calculus and taking limits at infinity...

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an indirect solution. If $y$ does not blow up in finite time, then the maximal solution is defined on all of $[0, \infty)$. We make the following two easy observations:

1. Sine $y' \geq 1$, we get $y(t) \geq t$.
2. Since $y' = 1 + y^{4} \geq 2y^{2}$, for any $0 < t_{0} < t_{1}$ we get
   $$ \frac{y'}{y^{2}} \geq 2 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \frac{1}{y(t_{0})} - \frac{1}{y(t_{1})} \geq 2(t_{1} - t_{0}). $$

Combining two observations, for any $0 < t_{0} < t_{1}$ we get

$$ \frac{1}{t_{0}} \geq \frac{1}{y(t_{0})} - \frac{1}{y(t_{1})} \geq 2 (t_{1} - t_{0}). $$

Then we get a contradiction by choosing large $t_{0}$ and $t_{1} = t_{0} + 1$.

Comment: This is exactly the abstraction I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

Let $y(t)$ be the solution, so that we know that $y(0)=0$ and $y'(t)=1+y(t)^4$. Clearly the function is strictly increasing in its domain, so it is positive on the positive part of its domain.

We have $\frac{y'(t)}{1+y(t)^4}=1$. Integrating this from $0$ to $\tau$, we have $\int_0^\tau\frac{y'(t)}{1+y(t)^4}dt=\tau$, and the integral can be rewritten as $\int_0^{y(\tau)}\frac{d\xi}{1+\xi^4}$, and this can be computed, so we  can conclude that $$
\frac{-\tan ^{-1}\left(1-\sqrt{2} y(t)\right)+\tan
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2} y(t)+1\right)+\tanh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2} y(t)}{y(t)^2+1}\right)}{2 \sqrt{2}}=\tau$$
for all $\tau$ in the positive part of the domain of $y$.
Now the function $$\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2} t}{t^2+1}\right)-\tan
   ^{-1}\left(1-\sqrt{2} t\right)+\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}
   t+1\right)}{2 \sqrt{2}}$$ is bounded. This means that the domain has to be bounded above. In fact, the upper limit of the domain has to be the limit value of this function, which is $\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: This is a nice "numerical" solution which yields the limit value of the interval (that's scarce!). I didn't choose it as an answer because it resort to a heavy computation that I couldn't have done by hand.

Comment: Well, integrating rational functions is a basic calculus skill, really, and the limit is very easy to compute!

Comment: Notice that you can bound from above $(1+\xi^4)^{-1}$ by $(1+\xi^2)^{-1}$ in the integral, and that integral and the corresponding limit you can surely do by memory :-)

Comment: I love this answer! (+1 upvote, too!) In fact, the only important point is that $(1 + \xi^{4})^{-1}$ is *integrable* on $[0, \infty)$. So if $\tau$ is the maximal time of existence, then $y(\tau^{-}) = \infty$ and hence $$ \tau = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d\xi}{1 + \xi^{4}} < \infty. $$

Comment: +1: Nice. While you are right that it is basic calculus, I would still struggle to get the integral correct in reasonable time without my Maxima...