# Obtaining a first-order ODE from a system of ODEs and then proving an asymptote exists

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, physics

I was debating whether to post this on the mathematics or physics StackExchange, and ultimately, I decided to post this here.

I have a system of differential equations which arose from a physics problem:
$$\ddot{r}=r\dot{\theta}^2$$
$$r\ddot{\theta}=\dot{r}\dot{\theta}$$
These are functions of $t$. The problem first asks me to show that:
$$\dot{r}=\sqrt{Ar^4+B}$$
And then show that $r=\infty$ in a finite amount of time.

To solve the first part of the problem, I was able to perform some manipulations to obtain:
$$\ddot{r}\dot{r}=\frac{1}{3}r\dddot{r}$$
And I found that the equation $\dot{r}=\sqrt{Ar^4+B}$ does indeed satisfy this.

As for the second part, I realize that the problem amounts to proving that there exists a vertical asymptote for the function $r(t)$. Graphing the slope field, this seems to be the case, though I have no idea how to prove it.

Any thoughts are appreciated. I'm not too content with my "solution" to the first part either, as it is rather indirect.

Comment: Do you know how to show the solution to $$\dot{x} = f(x,t)$$ is Lipschitz or not?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: Oh ok. Well, just so you know, given a function $f : \mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}$, a function is Lipschitz in the variable $x$ iff $$\lvert f(x,\cdot)-f(y,\cdot)\rvert\le L \lvert x-y\rvert\implies\frac{\lvert f(x,\cdot)-f(y,\cdot)\rvert}{\lvert x-y\rvert}\le L$$ which in turn implies that $\partial_{x}f$ is bounded. So essentially, you just need to compute $$\partial_{r}(\sqrt{Ar^{4}+B})$$ and show that it is unbounded somewhere. Another approach you can try is [following the solution given here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710480/the-equation-y-1y4-blows-up-in-finite-time).

Comment: @Mattos How does that help?

Comment: Interesting that $\theta$ itself does not show up. That allows an immediate integration of, say, $\varphi=\dot{\theta}$ to reduce your system to \begin{align*}\ddot{r}&=r\varphi^2\\r\dot{\varphi}&=\dot{r}\varphi.\end{align*} The solution of the second equation is most interesting: $\varphi(t)=C r(t).$

Comment: You can write the final solution in terms of the Jacobi elliptic functions.

Answer (score 1):

From $\varphi=\dot\theta,$ we have
\begin{align*}
\ddot{r}&=r\varphi^2\\
r\dot\varphi&=\dot{r}\varphi \\
\varphi&=Cr \quad\text{solve second equation for } \varphi \\
\ddot{r}&=C^2r^3 \\
\ddot{r} \dot{r}&=C^2r^3\dot{r} \\
\frac{\dot{r}^2}{2}&=\frac{C^2r^4}{4}+B.
\end{align*}
The first result follows from solving for $\dot{r},$ throwing away the negative square root (presumably on physical grounds), and re-labeling the arbitrary constants.

I don't have anything yet on your second part.

Comment: Ah yes, this is what I was looking for. The fact that the second equation could be solved by separation just completely flew over my head for some reason!

Comment: You can also solve it by the first-order linear integrating factor technique, and probably other methods as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that $\ddot{r} \dot{r} = r \dddot{r}/3$.  But it's not quite enough to show that a solution of $\dot{r} = \sqrt{A r^4 + B}$ satisfies this equation, you'd have to show that every solution of $\ddot{r} \dot{r} = r \dddot{r}/3$ satisfies $\dot{r} = \sqrt{ A r^4 + B}$ for some constants $A$ and $B$. And if $A$ and $B$ are supposed to be real, that can't be true (unless there are constraints you're not telling us about), because you can't get any solution with $\dot{r}(0) < 0$ that way.

Also, there are solutions that don't have $r \to \infty$ in finite time, e.g. (in terms of the original equations) $\theta = \text{constant}$, $r = a t + b$.